# Can a domain name be mapped to multiple ips

Tags: domain-name-system

I wanted to create a DNS entry for one domain to multiple ips like below :

```
example.com  111.111.111.111
example.com  222.222.222.222
```

Is this possible. If yes what record can we create like this, CNAME or A.
Also if I have SSL certificate already installed on both 111.111.111.111 and 222.222.222.222, do I need to recreate the CSR and recreate the certificate?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, that is possible, and will need to be two A records.  This is called Round-Robin DNS. Clients will semi-randomly use one of the two addresses.

The certificate is not tied to the IP address, only to the domain name,so if it is installed on both servers, there should be no issues with SSL.

Comment: "*Clients will semi-randomly use one of the two addresses*"... well, they should, but what clients do is strictly up to them, and if you rely on this behaviour you are likely to get disappointed some of the time!  Still +1 from me, though.

Comment: Quite :).Perhaps 'semi-randomly across the set of all clients'.Actual results may vary, random may not be random, no warranty, YMMV etc